# Prove that equality holds in Cauchy's estimate of coefficient for monomials only.

Tags: complex-analysis

> If $f(z)$ is analytic in the disk $|z|<R$ and has expansion
>   $$ f(z) = a_0 + a_1z + a_2z^2 + \cdots, $$
>   Cauchy's estimate states that
>   $$ |a_n| \le \frac{M(r)}{r^n} $$
>   where $M(r) = \max_{|z| = r} |f(z)|$ for any $r<R$.
>
> Now if for some $k$ and $0 < r_0 < R$,
>   $$ |a_k| = \frac{M(r_0)}{r_0^k}, $$
>   prove that
>   $$ f(z) = a_k z^k. $$

My first attempt was that the two equalities holds in
$$ |a_k| = \left|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=r_0} \frac{f(z)}{z^{k+1}}\,\mathrm{d}z\right| \le \frac{1}{r_0^k} \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{|z|=r_0} |f(z)|\,\mathrm{d}z \le \frac{M(r_0)}{r_0^k}$$
only if
$$ \arg\left(\frac{f(z)}{z^{k+1}}\,\mathrm{d}z\right) = \mathrm{const},\quad \mathrm{i.e.}\quad \arg\left(\frac{f(z)}{z^k}\right) = \mathrm{const}, $$
and
$$ |f(z)| = M(r_0) $$
on $|z| = r_0$. Together they imply that $f(z) = c_kz^k$ on $|z| = r_0$, and thus in $|z| < R$.

However, this proof seems really strange: notations like $\arg\left(\frac{f(z)}{z^{k+1}}\,\mathrm{d}z\right)$ is unconventional, and conditions for the equality in the triangle inequality to hold in hardly invoked elsewhere in complex analysis. There may be a proof more elegant than this one. I came across a similar question 
 [Find all entire functions () such that |()|=1 for ||=1 [duplicate]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/626488/find-all-entire-functions-fz-such-that-fz-1-for-z-1), but the strategy there seems inapplicable here.

The proof could be simpler if the equality
$$ |a_k| = \frac{M(r)}{r^k} $$
holds for some $k$ and *all* $0 < r < R$. Which shows $f(z) = O(|z|^k)$ and thus
$$ f(z) = a_kz^k + a_{k+1}z^{k+1} + \cdots. $$
Therefore $f(z)/z^k$ is analytic,
$$ \max_{|z| = r} \left|\frac{f(z)}{z^k}\right| = \frac{M(r)}{r^k} = |a_k|,\quad \forall r<R. $$
By maximum modulus principle, $f(z)/z^k = \mathrm{const}$. Is there also a simpler proof to the case where $ |a_k| = \frac{M(r)}{r^k} $ holds for some $r=r_0$ only?

Comment: Actually, I remember answering essentially a duplicate of this in the past. [Here it is](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2732858/173410). A rigorous proof did turn out to be more involved than I expected when I tried it too!